# NSTimer strange behaviour

Tags: ios, animation, nstimer

I have an `NSTimer` and I get a different results when I call a method or I try to fire that method using the timer.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:animationStepDuration
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(handleAnimation:)
                                       userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:newScale], @"scale",
                                                 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:offsetToCenter], @"offset",nil]
                                        repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

The result of handleAnimation: is different than this one.
Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Show the other 2/3 pieces of information: 2. How else are you calling it? 3. What does the animation method do?

Comment: What do you mean by "the result of `handleAnimation:` is different than this one"?